# JQuery val() does not work for textarea in Opera

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, opera

I am displaying a modal dialog using jQuery. This dialog has a `textarea` control on it. But while submitting this dialog, the value of this `textarea` is not recognized by jQuery for some reason: it always comes blank. 
This works perfectly in other browsers. I put alert to display the value but it looks blank. Can anybody help me in this regards?

Controls:

```
<input type="text" id="txtGroupName"/>
<textarea rows="3" cols="30" id="txtDescription"></textarea>
```

jQuery code which used this value:

```
var postData = new Object();
postData.GroupName = $('#txtGroupName').val();
postData.Description = $('#txtDescription').val();
```

`$('#txtDescription').val()` comes blank but `$('#txtGroupName').val()` is read correctly as it is a input field.

One more finding about this issue:

When I put alert in my update function after populating the control value on page load, this alert displays the existing value properly. But it displays only existing value. It does not display the edited value after submitting the modal box.

Comment: Which browser/platform are you using?

Comment: I am using Opera 10.53 and my OS is Windows 7.

Comment: I can't necessarily help with the Windows part, but I'll install Opera on my Ubuntu box and see if I can come up with anything useful.

Comment: after adding default text to the form on the jsbin demo (`<textarea>default text</textarea>`) and then editing the text to a new value/string and submitting it, it *still* seems to work fine on all the browsers I've tried so far (with Ubuntu). It might be a platform issue/bug with Opera and Windows 7. You've presumably cleared your cache, and such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix this using this in textarea

```
$("#descripcion").keydown(function(){
     $("#descripcion").css("display","block");
});
```

put at end of script.
I am sorry for my english

Answer (score 3):

val() and text() in jquery works correctly, but after setting value of textarea you need to 
rerender textarea, you can do this setting css property in such way

```
if ($.browser.opera)
    $('textarea').val(someText).css({display:block});
else
    $('textarea').val(someText);
```

Hello from Russia. Sorry for my english =)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `.attr("text")` or `.attr("value")`?  I'm unable to test this but this would seem logical to me.

If it doesn't then let me know and I'll remove this answer.

Comment: text gives 'undefined' and value gives blank

Answer (score 1):

you *may* have come across a very obscure bug referred to in a blog post on the Opera sitepatching blog [1](http://my.opera.com/sitepatching/blog/facebook-and-some-core-patches) as "PATCH-287, Hack to make script see typed value in TEXTAREA on blog.ebuddy.com. Opera fails to read correct value from a previously hidden textarea".

I'm a little bit reluctant to recomment workarounds without seeing the full code though.

Answer (score 1):

Good day people,

I too have the same problem with Opera 10.63 and Windows.

The hack suggested by Javier Canizalez works, but only as long as I don't reuse the dialog (and the textarea) again. However, this is not the case. With his hack, after the page is loaded and I click on an item, I display a dialog that was previously hidden (display:none) with textarea inside it. Everything works fine the first time (with the hack). After closing the dialog /* $(dialog).hide()); */ and reusing it again by clicking on another item, the hack does not work anymore and javascript/jQuery does not get the new typed value anymore until a full page reload.

I found at one of the links given above that the guys at opera have fixed that problem: PATCH-287
But it does not seems fixed to me :) I wrote a question there and will see if they'll reply:
[opera patch-287](http://my.opera.com/sitepatching/blog/facebook-and-some-core-patches)

Has someone managed to get a workaround this?

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea doesn't have a value attribute. Try to use

```
$('#txtDescription').text();
```

Comment: You are right it doesn't have a value attribute in HTML, but I'm pretty sure jQuery's `val()` will hand back the text node.

Answer (score 0):

I've found, in Chrome 6.0.472.59, Firefox 3.6.9 and Opera 10.62, all on Ubuntu 10.04, that `textarea` does have/use the `.val()` attribute. On the off-chance that some other browsers don't, or might not, I put together this [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/eyeqe3). I used an `if/else` block to cover both approaches, though. Just in case...

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
  $('form').submit(
    function() {

      if ($('textarea').val()) {
        var means = 'val()',
        textValue = $('textarea').val();
      }
      else {
        var means = 'text()',
        textValue = $('textarea').text();
      }

      alert('(' + means + ') ' + textValue);

      return false;
    }
    );
  }
  );
```

This Stackoverflow question ([jQuery get textarea text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144810/jquery-get-textarea-text)) also suggests that it should be possible and reliable, as does the first commenter on the API page for [Val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), at [jQuery.com](http://www.jquery.com/).

Note, as regards Opera: the jsBin demo only worked once I'd deactivated the developer tools (for whatever reason). It might be worth turning off Dragonfly (if it's running), and then refreshing the demo page (or, obviously, your own test page) to see if it makes a difference. Either way, it's always worth clearing your cache to make sure the most up-to-date version of the files are being used.

Comment: thanks for the approach. But thing is that text() as well as val() are not working here.

Comment: @Anil: you're *sure* that it's the `$('textarea').val();` bit that's not working? I realise that it's not the most canonical place to which I should refer, but one commenter on the http://api.jquery.com/val/ for the `.val()` function/method suggests that is *should* work (demonstrably so, in the cases of Chrome and FF on Ubuntu).

Comment: I used $("#txtDescription").val() because that is the id of my control. but not working. Do you want me to use $('textarea') instead? I assumed that 'textarea' should be replaced by my control's id.

Comment: @Anil: it's worth a *try* if all else fails. Though I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work regardless, given the correct (spelling of the) textarea's id.

Answer (score 0):

In opera for getting the value or a textarea works only:

document.getElementById("description").value;

strange is that $("textara#description").val("") works  (set method)

Comment: Same in Firefox, I needed to use `$("textarea#myelement").val("");` Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I use this workaround:

```
if (window.opera)
{
  document.addEventListener('focus', function(event){
    if (event.target instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement)
    {
      event.target.contentEditable = true;
      event.target.contentEditable = false;
    }
  }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select `<textarea>` by attribute name instead of id.

```
<textarea id="txtDescription" name="txtDescription"></textarea>
<script>
  jQuery("textarea[name='txtDescription']").val();
</script>
```