# jQuery - How to get selected text from textarea/input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [jQuery get textarea text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144810/jquery-get-textarea-text)
>   [How to get selected text in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea)

So I want to get the text selected within textarea.
val() returns entire text so that's no good.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I need the text that is currently selected in the textarea.

Comment: @Chris, he wants only the selected text, that is not a dup of the question.

Comment: no, it's not. the question is about getting the _selected_ text

Comment: @Chris Not quite, but it is definitely a dupe.

Comment: Argh, oops :) You're quite correct.

Comment: Try this: http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2009/7/31/RetrieveReplace-Selected-Text-With-jQuery

Comment: Oops, yes, dup of [How to get selected text in textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [field selection](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/field_selection) jQuery plugin should provide what you requested

Comment: this link doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the jQuery plugins website is down for some time. I think this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection) has the original code, though.