# jQuery Check if Input is deselected

Tags: jquery, input

So, I have a little form input box, `<input type ="text" />` and I can't seem to figure how to tell when it isn't being selected.
Anyone know?

Comment: Seems you may need to clarify "selected" (probably the reason for the downvote); so far you have 2 answers offering different definitions

Comment: Please quickly explain what the aim of this exercise is? To not allow the user to leave the field unlike something entered? Do be careful of never ending loops when you focus on blur. Use setTimeout if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regular input, maybe the following was what you're after - [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nwMDt/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').focusout(function(){
    alert('left input!');
  });
});
```

Comment: I mean input box, not checkbox.

Comment: @Ultimate What type of 'input box'? Textbox, number?

Comment: <input> <--That kind of input.

Comment: Yeah, that works, but when I try to get it to work (Trying to get it to reselect a input after they deselected) it completely doesn't work.

Comment: @Ultimate How doesn't it? It fires every time the input is left in the jsFiddle correctly, just like your question asks

Comment: Yeah but for my code it isn't working...well, I'll give you the answer, I probably have some code undoing it.

Comment: @Ultimate That's cool, you're one step closer - maybe post a new question with more of your code for the new problem, I am sure many people will want to help

Comment: Well, here's a example where it is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/MrPsau/tVgHJ/ When I deselect the input box, it should reselect it. But it does not.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could mean by "selected".

1. Focus (whether the user has selected it, i.e. when they type it will change)

   `var isFocussed = myInput.is(':focus');`
2. Checkbox being checked, in which case see zenith's answer
3. Textbox with selected text, in which case look at this question: [jQuery - How to get selected text from textarea/input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6091679/1180785)