# jQuery .attr('value') returns undefined for text area

Tags: jquery, undefined, attr

I have a page which dynamically brings in a form via ajax and displays it in a modal div (one that sits above an overlay div that covers the entire page). This is to let them save certain data before a window closes. Everything works great except one thing.

```
$('#save_close_form').find('*[name]').each(function(index, form_element) {
    var cfe = (form_element.jquery == undefined ? $(form_element) : form_element);
    console.log(cfe.attr('name') + " => " + cfe.attr('value'));
    if (cfe.attr('name').match(/data\[/)) {
        if (cfe.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
            if (cfe.attr('checked')) {
                map[cfe.attr('name')] = 'on';
            }
            else {
                map[cfe.attr('name')] = '';
            }
        }
        else if (cfe.attr('type') == 'radio') {
            // only get checked radio buttons
            if (cfe.attr('checked')) {
                map[cfe.attr('name')] = cfe.attr('value');
            }
        }
        else {
            map[cfe.attr('name')] = cfe.attr('value');
        }
    }
});
```

The part in the else {} clause at the end triggers for `TextArea` and `input type="text"` elements, but for some reason it always sees `cfe.attr('value');` as `undefined` for the `TextArea`. I'm using FF6.0 with jQuery 1.6 for this.

Comment: Why are you not using `cfe.val()`?

Comment: in a previous version of this code i tried that and it never worked. the weird thing is that the above code was working just fine until recently when i upgraded JQ from 1.3 to 1.6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`.

`<textarea>` doesn't have a `value` attribute (the text is between the tags, not in `value=""`) however I believe `.val()` will retrieve it.

Comment: I guess in 1.6 they fixed the way .val() works in textareas, as it now seems to work with that. The strange thing is that .attr('value') was working fine until now.

Answer (score 2):

For textareas use :

```
 $("#textareaid").val() or $("#textareaid").html()
```

instead.

[jQuery get textarea text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144810/jquery-get-textarea-text)

[Set value of textarea in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery)

Comment: `.html()` will get the value the textarea started with, `.val()` will get the current value.

Answer (score 1):

TextArea does not have an attribute called value...try using val

```
map[cfe.attr('name')] = cfe.val();
```

Answer (score 1):

`textarea` does not have a `value` attribute by default. You should use `cfe.val()` or `cfe.html()` to get its content.

Answer (score 0):

It's because a textarea doesn't have a value attribute.

Use `.val()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the reason is that jQuery 1.6 makes a distinction between the attribute at creation and your current property value. You've created the textarea without a value attribute more than likely; thus, the initial value is `undefined`. When you want to pull the defined value, you need to either use `.prop('value')`, or call the more helpful `.val()` method.