# Read textarea via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

What is the proper way to extract the value of a textarea in a form via javascript?

```
var subject = $("input#subject").val();
if (subject == "") {
    $("label#subject_error").show();
    $("input#subject").focus();
    return false;
}
var description = $("textarea#description").val();
if (description == "") {
    $("label#description_error").show();
    $("Textarea#description").focus();
    return false;
}
```

The `$("input#subject").val()` works fine but not the `$("textarea#description").val()`.  Must be a noob error I'm missing.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `textarea` element with an `id` attribute of "description" on your page?

Comment: What `doesnt work` about it? what happens?

Comment: works fine: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8zKU/1/)

Comment: It's not causing your problem, but note that when selecting an element by id the element tagname is redundant. So use `$("#description")` rather than `$("textarea#description")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *ought* to work. Can you verify that 1) your textarea element includes attribute `id="description"` and that 2) no *other* element on the page has and id of `description`?

Comment: Although the others are valid answers. This was the right one in my case. I somehow missed the id="description" in the form.  Don't know how I missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

`TEXTAREA` has `innerHTML`,  not value.

```
$("textarea#description").html()
```

Comment: moot point considering OP is using jQuery, which knows this exception and plans accordingly for `.val()` -- **EDIT** [Reference to relative code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L165-169)

Comment: According to the jQuery documentation and several posts here on SO, `.val()` does indeed work with the textarea-element, even though the element doesn't have a value-attribute.

Comment: `$("<textarea>a</textarea>").get(0).value === "a"`, so it actually does have `value` available.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario should work fine. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMJz4/).

Are you sure that you have a `textarea#description` on your page?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried `$('textarea').val()` in Chrome Dev Tools on this page can get the value of the textarea, so I'm unsure as to why this isn't working for you.

Indeed, I then just found this: [jQuery get textarea text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144810/jquery-get-textarea-text)

One other point, you're over-qualifying your selectors by mentioning the element name if they already have an ID. As IDs can only apply to one element on the page, just use the ID in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){
    var txt = document.getElementById("t").value;
    alert(txt);
}
</script>
    </head>

   <body>
     <textarea id="t" rows="30" cols="40"> Hello to text area </textarea>
   </body>
   </html>
```