# TextArea returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have some TextAreas

```
<textarea>Default Value</textarea>
<textarea>Default Value</textarea>
```

The user enters some text and I want to get their NEW values in JavaScript:

```
$('textarea').each(function(index, item) {
    alert(item.value);
});
```

It sounds simple, but all I get is "Default Value".

I've tried:

```
item.nodeValue, 
item.textContent, 
item.innerHTML. item.innerText, 
item.value, 
$(item).val() in jQuery
```

I'm always getting "Default Value". Though firebug even shows the new value in HtmlTextAreaElement => value. That should be `item.value`, right? I feel stupid, please help me.

Comment: Take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144810/jquery-get-textarea-text

Comment: [Your code already works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/aNzzG/)

Comment: do you tried `$(this).val()`?

Comment: Okay thanks for pointing that out, now I know what the problem is: My TextAreas are nested into some containers, what I'm trying to access is actually a clone of their 2nd parent. jQuery seems to lose all the values in the process, even with .clone(true, true);

Answer (score 0):

in textarea it's not item.value, it's innerHTML

jquery's val() works though

```
<input type="text" value="some text" />
<textarea id="something" name="something">some text</textarea>
```

you can do:

```
$('textarea').each(function(index, item){
    console.log($(item).val());
});
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect. The "value" attribute of a `<textarea>` DOM node reflects the current value of the element, that being the contents as updated by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Give your textareas a "name" attribute

`<textarea name="name">innterHTML</textarea>`

and use

> item.innerHTML

as suggested, for textarea it is innerHTML, not value :)

Answer (score 0):

> The user enters some text and I want to get their NEW values in
>   JavaScript:

This should do it:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
   alert(this.value);
});
```

To read **already entered value** (not when user types it), use:

```
$('textarea').each(function(index, item) {
    alert(this.value);
});
```