# how to get the text inside the textarea using jquery and display on the html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery get textarea text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144810/jquery-get-textarea-text)

So i have a text area that takes the users input. How do i get text inside the text area and put it in my `<div id="prev">` inside `<p>` tag?
i tried using this:

```
function displayCustom() {
    var customText = $('textarea#custom').val();
    $('prev p').text(customText);   //<-- this doesnt work
    //alert(text); <-- if i try using this it works
}
```

Comment: Without HTML it's hard to tell what's going on, but you say you have "`<div id="prev">` inside `<p>` tag" so that leads me to believe the div is inside the p tag?

Comment: Your selector is the problem `$('prev p')` what is prev? Are you trying to use jQuery's `.prev()` selector? or is prev a css class or ID?

Comment: i have div with id prev that contain <p> inside it

Comment: then use the selector `#prev` and it will work. `prev` is not a valid selector if you're targeting an ID.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `#` for the ID selector:

```
$('#prev p').text(customText);
```

Comment: the other wrong point is getting the text area content ... not a complete answer

Comment: @Reflective What is the complete answer?

Comment: This works thanks I forgot the #

Comment: @Reflective Eh? The value of the `textarea` is taken correctly in the OP's code, since `alert(customText)` works fine. The answer is full and correct.

Comment: following the good practices  .text() or .html() should be used ... .val() is made for competability ... it will work but doesn't show a good style

Comment: @Reflective Please read the docs. _The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea._

Comment: form elements have diferent style - '.val()' normally represent attribute value which is not present in textarea ... value is present in input,select, button and many other ... but textarea is different `<textarea>.... text </textarea>` ... so the good style  requers to use .text() ... that's my oppinion

Comment: @Reflective This is completely _wrong_,  `val` reads the `value` _property_, what you are saying is `attr('value')`.

Comment: Note: At present, using .val() on textarea elements strips carriage return characters from the browser-reported value. If you have to getthe exact value you should use .html()

Answer (score -2):

You can append your text inside `<p>` like this:

```
 var customText = $('#custom').val();
 $('#prev').append('<p>'+customText+'</p>');
```

Comment: bad solution...assumes OP wants a new P tag and not replace content of an existing one. Only problem was a bad selector to begin with