# jquery how to get element html plus text of an textarea element

Tags: jquery

I will be straight to the point. I created a textarea element and I have to return the tag html plus the text inside.

```
var elemField = $('<textarea></textarea>');
elemField.val('bla bla this is my textarea text');
//changing some properties
elemField.attr("disabled", "disabled");
elemField.width('95%');
```

found this solution:

```
var elemFeldCode = elemField.clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html().toString();
```

Output:

```
"<textarea disabled="disabled" style="width: 95%;"></textarea>"
```

Desired Output:

```
"<textarea disabled="disabled" style="width: 95%;">bla bla this is my textarea text</textarea>"
```

Any one can help me to have this result in a cross browser manner throw jquery?!

Comment: Use val method ... Check this >[Stackoverflowthread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144810/jquery-get-textarea-text)<

Comment: @f00bar pls read the post well I don't want the textarea text, look the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your desired output you'll have to use `.text()` to set the content of the text area as `.val()` does not affect the html of the node.

```
elemField.text('bla bla this is my textarea text');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/H5U3s/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add it explicitly:

```
var elemFeldCode = elemField.clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html()
    .replace('</',elemField.val()+'</').toString();
```