# How to read text from textfield using jQuery to the variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I got the page on my local server, and this page contains textarea and button. I am Trying to write onclick function to button, which would read whatever I typed in text area, and make record to database. Just like when I finish typing my question here, and press Ask Question. The problem is that I can't properly read text in text area, it basically sees only what was in there at the moment of loading a page, and just rewrite it. How should I get text, that I typed right before clicking the button? I just want to know how can I copy that text to some var, which I can PUT to database.

```
$.getJSON('/link/' + tenderId, function (data) { 
     var description = ''; 
     description += '<textarea id="description" class="form-control" rows="3">' + data.description + '</textarea>'; 
     $('#description').html(description); 
});
```

Comment: can you please share your html and jquery that you have tried so far?

Comment: HTML too please? That jQuery code is invalid  as it creates elements with ids that are duplicates of an existing id (`description`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `val()` (I am guessing you are using `text()`) to get the text of a Text Area:

```
$('input#mybutton').click(function() {
    var text = $('textarea#mytextarea').val();
});
```

Of course this is just guesswork *as you did not supply any code!* :)

### Update:

The code you added is also incorrect as it adds a duplicate id of `description` inside a div with an id of `description`! *ID's need to be unique on a page.*

Assuming you want a new id here is a cleaner version of your code:

```
$.getJSON('/link/' + tenderId, function (data) {
    var $textArea = $("<textarea>", {class: "form-control", id: "descriptionText", rows: "3"}).val(data.description);
    $('#description').empty().append(description);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside your click event

```
var textareaValue = $('textarea#textareaId').val();
```

html

```
<textarea id="textareaId"></textarea>
```

SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/144836/2772017

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function(){
var myString = $('#description').val();
})
```

Then use myString whereever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out you method logic; it seems you are pulling some json data then appending it to a textarea while in issue description you said that you are trying to save the `textarea` content so you have to be sending it throug a POST request.

Also does the `<textarea id="description"...>` element is there in your page or you will be creating it at each button click?
If such is you case, you can try with the following snippet:

```
$.getJSON('/link/' + tenderId, function (data) { 
  var $description = $("<textarea>");
  $description.attr({
      id:'description',
      class:'form-control',
      rows:'3'})
    .html(data.description);
//you will have then to append this jQuery element, e.g: $("#wrapper").append($description)
});
```